# Image to the right on desktop, centered on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am making a website with bootstrap. In my jumbotron, I have some text to the left, and an image to the right. On mobile, the image appears on the top instead.

**How it looks on desktop:**
[image]

**How it looks on mobile:**
[image]
The problem is, on mobile, it would be nicer if the image was centered, instead of floated to the right. Is that possible?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container" id="main">

    <div class="img"
        <p id="pic"><img id="pic" src="http://cube.crider.co.uk/visualcube.php?fmt=png&amp;size=800&amp;bg=t&amp;alg=F2%20D2%20L2%20F2%20L2%20F%20U2%20R2%20L%20U%27%20B%20D%27%20F%27%20U2%20L%20D2%20L2%20F2" width="300px" height="300px"></p> 
    </div>

    <h1>Example </h1>
    <p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</p>
    <p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</p>
    <p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
```

[Example website](http://speedcubing.no/example/example2.html)

Comment: Dear editor of my post, the reason i didn't post images was because I didn't have enough reputation. Just so you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this below code in to your css:

```
.img{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline;
} 

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .img{
        float:none;
        display:table;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    }
```

or

```
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px)
.img {
  /* float: none; */
  /* display: table; */
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  TEXT-ALIGN: CENTER;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

first enclose your text in `<div>`:

```
<div id="textwithimg">
    <h1>Example </h1>
    <p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</p>
    <p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</p>
    <p>Example Example Example Example Example Example Example</p>
</div>
```

then use media queries :

```
//for mobile 
       @media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 500px) {
        .img{
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 70%;
            background-color: #b0e0e6;
            }
        }
    //normal css for any size 
          .img{
              float: right;
              margin-right: 40px;
              margin-bottom: 20px;
              display: inline;
           } 
           #textwithimg{
              desplay:inline;
              float:left;
            }
```